# Geofencing status on browser

Tags: javascript, browser, service-worker, geofencing

It seems like w3c has abandoned the [Geofencing API](https://w3c.github.io/geofencing-api/). Is there any browser that still supports it?

I need to a functionality to alert the server whenever the user is within a certain radius of a location, even after the user reboots the phone.

Comment: use google lib https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circles

Comment: @TarangRathod what has that link got to do with getting the user's geolocation?

Comment: this is how you can use Drawing Tools of Google Maps API for geofencing Those overlays- Circle, Polygon, Rectangle, Polyline can be stored in the database.

Comment: @TarangRathod Geofencing is not about drawing fences..."The Geofencing API lets webapps set up geographic boundaries around specific locations and then receive notifications when the hosting device enters or leaves those areas. The Geofencing API is built around Service Workers. This makes it possible for a webapp to receive notifications from the Geofencing API even after the user has closed the webapp."

Comment: that what you can do by setting these and set an alarm once some this gets out of these bounds read the API you'll get what I am saying

Comment: @TarangRathod the doc requires the Google Maps API. Service workers don't have access to that. Do you have any example snippet of it working even when the browser is closed?

Comment: Maybe this node.js module meight help you: https://bitbucket.org/teqplay/geolocation-utils